# sharing asp session over virtual directory

Tags: session, asp-classic

In IIS I have asp (classic) site. In that site there is virtual directory. Is there any way to share session between those two web applications?

tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but real complicated. Basically, you'll have to make the Session state save in a database rather than in memory. When it's in memory, it'll be scoped to the web application but if you have it in a database, both applications should be able to read it. Here's an article about sharing sessions between asp and asp.net sites. The concept should be the same because they'll be in different web applications:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx